# Python: Encoding Error - content of web page

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to get a content of a web page and parse it than save in mysql db.

I actually did it for a web page encoding utf8.

But when i tried with a 8859-9 encoding webpage i get error.

My code to get content of page:

```
def getcontent(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Magic Browser')]
    opener.addheaders = [('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8')]   
    #print chardet.detect(response).get('encoding)
    response = opener.open(url).read()
    opener.close()
    return response



url     = "http://www.meb.gov.tr/duyurular/index.asp?ID=4"
contentofpage = getcontent(url)
print contentofpage
print chardet.detect(contentofpage)
print contentofpage.encode("utf-8")
```

output of content of page:
    ...
    E�itim Teknolojileri Genel M�d�rl���
    ...

```
{'confidence': 0.7789909202570836, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2'}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "meb.py", line 18, in <module>
    print contentofpage.encode("utf-8")
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 458: ordinal not     in range(128)
```

Actually page is a Turkish page and encoding is 8859-9.

When i tried with default encoding all i see ��� instead of some chars. How can i take or convert content of page to  utf-8 or turkish (iso-8859-9)

Also when i use 
unicode(contentofpage)

it get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "meb.py", line 20, in 
    print unicode(contentofpage)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 458: ordinal not in range(128)

any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to decode, not encode, since it is already encoded.

```
print contentofpage.decode("iso-8859-9")
```

yields a sample like:

```
Eğitim Teknolojileri Genel Müdürlüğü
```

Comment: print contentofpage.decode("iso-8859-9")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xee' in position 458: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Make sure you are decoding directly after getting the content.  `contentofpage = getcontent(url)`, then `print contentofpage.decode('iso-8859-9')`.